# Why the child class output is comming before the parent class or Base class

Tags: php, oop

Say there are three member variable `$a, $b,$c`, where $a & $b are from base class and & c is in child class ... values are assigning to `$a,$b,$c` from child class..Thus when outputting the values in this format $a.$b.$c but the output is coming in format $c.$a.$b....the child class variable is coming first.

Comment: Please share your code too.

Comment: thing is that i have tried to share but I am not able to do it

Comment: If you can share your mail id I could send it there

Comment: Can't you share a code sample in your above post?

Comment: You can share your code here https://eval.in/ so that other SO users can see.

Comment: I have tried to share it but it cant..I am new in SOF...

Comment: did you notice that edit anchor tag @AvijitPaul

Comment: https://eval.in/795895 .......Cheeck here

Comment: I have pasted my code in this link : https://eval.in/795895

Comment: echo $this->pub_name; your echoing you need to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method that should be returning a value but is instead echoing it:

```
function getname()
{
    echo $this->pub_name;
}
```

As such you're getting an unexpected result when using it as part of another echo statement.

Change:

```
echo $this->pub_name;
```

To:

```
return $this->pub_name;
```